# OSC library working on iOS6 with ARC

Tags: objective-c, c, ios6, automatic-ref-counting, osc

Now I'm looking for OSC library which working on iOS6 with ARC.
I tried vvOSC at first. 
But I got an error with "- (NSString *) stringByDeletingLastAndAddingFirstSlash;"
Maybe Compiler can't find the method.

Then I tried to compile liblo for iOS6. I googled the way to do that. But I couldn't find an example. I have no idea with UINIX, so I gave up liblo.

Then I tried CocoaOSC. Actually the sample code works fine with iPhone simulator6.1. But The example doesn't use ARC and when I used CocoaOSC on my project which uses ARC, I got so many errors. I removed memory management things in CocoaOSC like 'autorelease, retain, etc..'.

I am kind of new at Objective-C. So I don't think I can resolve CocoaOSC problem with ARC.

So if someone knows good OSC library for iOS6 with ARC. Please tell me that.

Excuse for my poor English.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

Answer (score 2):

You can mix and match ARC and non-ARC code. You simply need to set the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag for each implementation file you want to not use ARC. This will allow you to easily mix non-ARC libraries with ARC code.

Given this, is there a specific reason why you need an ARC library?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have made my app with an ARC. And if I don't use an ARC, I need to fix so many codes. That is why I am looking for an ARC library. I have tried -fno-objc-arc. But I still have problem. I will try -fno-objc-arc way again today and will specify what's wrong.

Comment: Hi, I solved the problem. The problem was that I did not delete unnecessary compile resources. Anyway, thanks for your help. I think CocoaOSC is the best library for iOS6 at the moment.

Comment: Hi Kei , I am also facing same issue with VVOSC framework .Can you tell me process which you followed to solve this issue?